# Rails or Jquery WYSIWYG

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg

I'm pretty much just looking for the code they used that is very similar this this WYSIWYG when adding a comment.  I want them to be able to hit return and it automatically throws in a `<br />` tag. I know very simple way to get it to work in a text area if they know the HTML tags, but almost no users will.  So I just want a few buttons like bold, italic, and link and have it automatically do `<br />`'s on return.  Nothing real fancy.

It can be either a jquery or a rails solution as I am using both. Thanks for any leads/help. I looked briefly into some like TinyMCE, but those do a lot more than I want users to be able to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used fckeditor, fairly easy to get running:

http://www.fckeditor.net/

but will consider the Yahoo rich text editor for my next app:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/

Comment: I tried out the Yahoo RTE.  It's pretty decent and I have it functioning except when I click submit the text in the textarea isn't getting submitted to the database. If I work that out, then I'll go with this one.

Comment: I got that working. Now my only issue is with the link function. Say i want the link to go to www.yahoo.com. I tries to take me to www.mysite.com/www.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Try a combo of [RecCloth](http://redcloth.org/) and [TEH](http://slateinfo.blogs.wvu.edu/plugins/textile_editor_helper). To have it show up under the text area as they type look into [observe_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001654).

Comment: The documentation for RedCloth is horrible. Can you give me a sample of how to implement it into rails code?

Comment: Sure. First install the gem - gem install RedCloth. Then in your view pass some text for it to format - RedCloth.new(@my_text).to_html. Any textile formatted text will be processed, so your database just stores plain text. Here's a reference for textile: http://redcloth.org/textile/. The documentation is short because there's just not that much to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but you could have a look at [wysihat](http://github.com/josh/wysihat/tree/master). I haven't used it before, but it does look promising for some basic 'rich text' formatting.

Or, you could use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to format the copy that the user inputted. There are a bunch of libraries that will parse Markdown, I typically use [RDiscount](http://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount/).

Hope this helps. Cheers.